# What is the difference between procrank and dumpsys meminfo?

Tags: android, dumpsys

I felt confused about the difference between procrank and dumpsys meminfo when using Android adb shell.The Pss of my application, which is reported by the command-procrank, is always higher than the one displayed in the result of dumpsys meminfo.Could anyone tell me the difference between the two command-procrank and dumpsys meminfo.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the source of procrank and meminfo, they both take values from /proc/meminfo. The differences in memory usage may be from the difference in time between calling procrank and meminfo.

(Although this is a really old question, hopefully anyone else coming across it from a Google search will find this useful)